# knockout.js load widget from javascript library

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, widget

I'm trying to add a widget into an existing application that uses knockout.  The documentation for this widget is pretty sparse.  The documentation instructs me to place

```
<script>Widget.insertWidget({"productId":"1234"});</script>
```

into my page where I want the widget to display.

This project is using haml and I've been able to get the example working by doing the following

```
%div
  :javascript
    Widget.insertWidget({"productId":"1234"})
```

This gets the example to work, but I need to have that `productId`, which is a property on a knockout observable.

So I'm trying to implement the bindings and that's where I'm stuck.  I've tried variations of

```
%div{ 'data-bind' => "(text|html|value) => $parent.widgetInserter" }
```

Where `widgetInserter` is

```
widgetInserter: =>
  Widget.insertWidget({"productId":@product().id})
```

I'm able to hit a `debugger` statement inside my `insertWidget` function, but the widget isn't being displayed.

To me it seems like one of those should have worked, but none have.  I appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: `"(text|html|value) => $parent.widgetInserter"` - Why you are using `=>` here? In knockout you need use `:`. And here I suppose you need custom binding to execute your function. See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't access the same Knockout view model from the other `<script>`, then bind the product ID to a hidden input:

`<input type="hidden" data-bind="value: productId" id="pid" />`

Then later access it:

```
%div
  :javascript
    var productId = document.querySelector('#pid').value;
    Widget.insertWidget({"productId": productId})
```

Comment: That's actually a pretty clever idea.  I ended up figuring out a workaround based on the internals of the `Widget` object, but this would have been a nice solution.  Thanks!